# App not authenticated with Firebase. Permission Denied error

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been following this [guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html) to add and retrieve items from firebase using React  Native. If I set my rules on firebase to public, everything works but if I set it to the following, I get a permission denied error.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I have added all of my config data properly in my ios.js. Is there some basic step that I am missing here?

index.ios.js:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'myapikey',
  authDomain: 'myauthdomain',
  databaseURL: 'https://url.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'myProjectId',
  storageBucket: 'projectid.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'myMessagingSenderId'
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class MyNewAppreactold extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items');
  }

  getRef() {
    return firebaseApp.database().ref();
  }

  listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          title: child.val().title,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
      });

    });
  }

  // componentWillMount() {
  //       firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  //   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <StatusBar title="Grocery List" />

        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          style={styles.listview}/>

        <ActionButton onPress={this._addItem.bind(this)} title="Add" />

      </View>
    )
  }

  _addItem() {
    AlertIOS.prompt(
      'Add New Item',
      null,
      [
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
        {
          text: 'Add',
          onPress: (text) => {
            this.itemsRef.push({ title: text })
          }
        },
      ],
      'plain-text'
    );
  }

  _renderItem(item) {

    const onPress = () => {
      AlertIOS.alert(
        'Complete',
        null,
        [
          {text: 'Complete', onPress: (text) => this.itemsRef.child(item._key).remove()},
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: (text) => console.log('Cancelled')}
        ]
      );
    };

    return (
      <ListItem item={item} onPress={onPress} />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyNewAppreactold', () => MyNewAppreactold);
```

Comment: check this firebase presentation it can be very helpfull => https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared doesn't authenticate the user. Since your security rules require that the user is authenticated to be allowed access to the data, they reject the unauthenticated user of your app.

To solve this problem, you'll need to authenticate the user. The simplest way to do that is to [sign the user in anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously):

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
```

Then attach your database listeners after the user is authenticated:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
```